# Topological band crossing and central charge

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, conformal-field-theory, topological-insulators

Conventionally for a 1D topological insulator, SSH model for example, the low energy assumes a linear dispersion i.e. Dirac cone at a topological phase transition point, thus obeys the massless Dirac equation. Meanwhile, we may compute entanglement entropy and use [Calabrese-Cardy formula](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4013) to obtain the central charge which is exactly $c=1$ for the SSH model at a critical point.

Now here are my questions:

1.Does there exists a direct connection between the Dirac cone and central charge?

2.Is this linear dispersion a necessary condition for the central charge $c=1$? If I change the linear dispersion to a quadratic one, will the central charge vary as well?

Comment: What kind of connection are you looking for? A Dirac fermion in 1+1 is a c=1 CFT. Are you looking for the derivation?

Comment: @MengCheng Sure, if there are references I would be most grateful. Besides, what do other kinds of band crossings mean in CFT for example quadratic?

Comment: CFT has linear dispersion. If the dispersion is quadratic, then it is not a CFT.